# React Native: Module RCTLog is not a registered callable module (calling logIfNoNativeHook)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, package

I made a **React Native** package and published it on npm.

The problem is when I run the code as a normal component inside **React Native** app it's work fine with no errors.

When I publish the package on **Npm** and download it to my project as a dependency the app is throwing red screen error.

The error is:

```
Invariant Violation: Module RCTLog is not a registered callable module (calling logIfNoNativeHook)

__callFunction
    index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:109413:18
<unknown>
    index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:109128:31
__guard
    index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:109369:15
callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
    index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:109127:21
callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
    [native code]:0
```

> Note: All the code available on [Github](https://github.com/yamankatby/react-native-progress-overlay)
>   and the package is available on [Npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-progress-overlay) if you can install it and give me feedback if you get the same error of not also it can be helpful

Answer (score 0):

The reason is probably due to [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/8663).

I would try to implement the suggestion above to basically add this `var RCTLog = require('RCTLog');` into the index.ios.js file.

Comment: That issue is from 2016, and I'm getting it today in RN version 60.5.  Surely theres a new fix elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Usually caused by a corrupt cache.

1. Stop metro bundler
2. `rm -rf $TMPDIR/metro-cache/`
3. Start bundler again (`react-native start`)

Answer (score -1):

I created Expo snack by using your package and didn't receive any issue, tested on IOS and Android.
Expo snack: https://snack.expo.io/@djalik/progressoverlay

[image: Android View][image: iOS View]